# The map $A\mapsto A^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, chain-rule

The Inverse Function Theorem states that for a continuously differentiable $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n$ with non-vanishing Jacobian is a homeomorphism around a small neighborhood, and that
$$
(f^{-1})'(y)=[f'(f^{-1}(y))]^{-1}.
$$
I have seen a stronger claim that if $f$ is $C^{\infty}$ then $f^{-1}$ is also one (i.e. $f$ is a diffeomorphism in that small neighborhood). I observed that we have the relation
$$
(f^{-1})' = \Bbb I \circ f' \circ f^{-1}
$$
where $\Bbb I:GL(\Bbb R^n)\to GL(\Bbb R^n)$ is the mapping $A\mapsto A^{-1}$. By chain rule and induction, it appears that we only need to show that $\Bbb I$ is $C^{\infty}$. My questions are:

1. What does the chain rule look like for composition with function of class $GL(\Bbb R^n)\to GL(\Bbb R^n)$? Is it the same as the usual $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ and $g:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^k$?
2. How does one show that $\Bbb I$ is $C^{\infty}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The chain rule works the same in this context.
2. This function is a rational function, and therefore a $C^\infty$ function. This is so because $A^{-1}=\frac1{\det A}\operatorname{adj}(A)$, where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the [adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) of $A$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on the phrase "This function is a rational function"? I myself am not very familiar with differentiation in maltivariables setting.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I have edited my answer.

Comment: Oh you meant it is a rational function of the entries of the matrix $A$? This might seem extremely silly to ask but why does that imply $C^{\infty}$? My knowledge in this area is really limited.

Comment: @BigbearZzz: composition of smooth functions is smooth, addition is smooth, multiplication is smooth, division is smooth so long as the denominator is non-zero, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I still fail to see why the adjoint of $A$ is a smooth function of $A$. Would you mind explain this step or, if you wouldn't mind, recommend me a book about this?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Adjoint? Who said anything about adjoint matrices?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I thought it was synonymous to adjugate matrix. I didn't mean adjoint in operator sense.

Comment: @BigbearZzz Each entry of the adjugate matrix of $A$ is a polynomial function of $A$.

Comment: So the operation of forming a matrix whose entries are smooth (as functions of $A$) is itself smooth?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Sure.

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much. Lastly, could you please recommend me a book that treat this kind of subject? I found my background in multivariables calculus to be lacking, which is really a shame.

Comment: @BigbearZzz *Elementary Classical Analysis* by J. E. Marsden and M. J. Hoffman, for instance.